# Spring app doesn't find datasource in config files

Tags: spring, configuration, datasource, jndi

When I deploy my spring app (Spring 2.5.6) onto a Tomcat (6.0), start up fails with

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [C.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="[snip]" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>[snip]</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
   [snip]
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:All.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>[snip]</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>[snip]</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

All.xml imports a number of configuration files:

```
<import resource="A.xml"/>
<import resource="B.xml"/>
<import resource="C.xml"/>
...
```

B.xml defines a data source:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="[snip]"/>
```

C.xml creates a hibernate session factory, referencing the data source from B.xml:

```
<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>[snip]</value>
            <value>[snip]</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
  <props>
       [snip]
  </props>
</property>
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

When I deploy my WAR file, above exception occurs. My questions are:

1. Why?
2. Why does the same exception not occur in my JUnit test that I wrote to test the validity of the spring configuration? Here's the test:

   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/All.xml" })
   public class ImfSpringConfigurationTest {
     [snip]]
   }

Note: In the JUnit test, I use a different All.xml file to replace B.xml with a file that defines a data source without jndi lookup, like so:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    [snip] />
```

**

Turns out, this configuration is correct. It was the deploy of another module operating on some of the same config files that threw the exception, not this deploy process.

Answer (score 0):

Try pull in the top level context using a wildcard operator :

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/spring*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Sorry, this assumes that your contexts aren't called A B C etc. and share some common prefix. I know i've had problems with the import hierarchy just as you have before.

Comment: Sorry mate, false alarm. Exception was from another war file deploy. Thanks anyway.